# How to change inner box-shadow color with jquery or somehow?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the box-shadow color as a result of the value I am getting from a database.

basically what I am doing is:

```
if (dbValue==1)
      $('.myDivClass').css("box-shadow","0px 0px 30px #333333");
else
 $('.myDivClass').css("box-shadow","0px 0px 30px #999999");
```

for the browser support I should set this value for `-webkit` `-moz` as well.

I think this is not supported  and also it needs to have the inset value somewhere to make it inner box shadow.

I have searched for jquery plugins as well and I found out the `boxShadow` method which only changes outside shadow color. Is there any way of doing this? Am I missing something. What I can do I think is to create different css classes with different inner `box-shadow`'s and with jquery I can add and delete the class into a div to change the `box-shadow`. this seems to me an alternative way of doing it but I want to make sure that if there is no way of changing the color of

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #257d0d;
```

this `box-shadow` directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably just add a class to the element instead.

CSS:

```
.boxShadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #333333;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #333333;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #333333;
}
.boxShadow2 {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #999999;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #999999;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px #999999;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if (dbValue==1)
      $('.myDivClass').removeClass('boxShadow boxShadow2').addClass('boxShadow');
else
 $('.myDivClass').removeClass('boxShadow boxShadow2').addClass('boxShadow2');
```

As you can see I made the box shadow inset for you also if you wanted it to be an inset box shadow.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** *I edited my code to remove each class before a new one is added just in case someone needs it someday...*

Comment: Do I need to remove the other class first before I add the one which I want to show?

Comment: Nope, because elements can have more than one class. So you won't have to remove any classes. :)

Comment: I knew that but what confuses me here is that imagine I will have an element and if I dont remove one of the boxShadow classes and keep adding them how is it gonna work it out and which one will be applied to the element? The other thing I am also wondering is that because this function will be called every 10 sec so every 10 sec I will be adding the class into the element. so If an element already has the same class and if I try to add same class how does it act? is there any mechanism there to check it or it will keep adding the same name class in the div?thanks:)

Comment: You could remove each class before you add another. If you need a code snippet for that let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    .boxShadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(1,2,3,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(1,2,3,0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(1,2,3,0);
}

$('#m-div').css('box-shadow').replace(/rgba\([1\s]+,[2\s]+,[3\s]+,[0\s]+\)+/g,'red')
```

i use reg-ex because in some browsers one color can be returned using different format for example transparent is returned in chrome as rgba(0,0,0,0)